# Existe algún comando en termux para cambiar este ajuste en opciones de desarrollador en Android 10?

Tags: android

Básicamente usó Android 10 y cada vez que reinicio el teléfono este ajuste se reinicia a un valor cero, me gustaría saber si existe algún comando en termux o en adb que sea capaz de cambiarlo, este ajuste me sirve para ahorrar un poco de batería y ram

[image]